# Loading time shared library too large

Tags: python

I'm connecting one lib(*.so) with ctypes. However, the loading time is very large. That is very slow.

What technique can I use to improve performance?

My module will always run at the prompt. Will run a command at a time.

```
> $./myrunlib.py fileQuestion fileAnswer 
# again
> $./myrunlib.py fileQuestion fileAnswer
```

code:

```
from ctypes import *
drv = cdll.LoadLibrary('/usr/lib/libXPTO.so')
```

Comment: please show us the code you're using, otherwise we really can't help...

Comment: Does a simple C program to load the same .so also take a long time?

Answer (score 0):

Either you've got a strange bug which makes your library load extremely slowly when used by a Python program (which I find rather unlikely), or the loading take the time it takes (maybe because the library does a large initialization task upon being loaded).

In the latter case your only option seems to be to prevent any restarts of your Python program.  Let it run in a loop which reads all tasks from stdin (or any other pipe or socket or maybe even from job files) instead of from the command line.

Comment: Alfe, Thanks for the suggestions (Daemon, socket, etc. ..). But I want to make an attempt to optimize running from the command line.

Comment: Then have a look at how long loading takes when this library is loaded from a "normal" C program (@abarnert's suggestion).  If that also takes as long, you'll have to optimize the library itself, I fear.

Comment: Good idea! I'll try to load into C and measure time.